# Scala mutable collections and "Reference must be prefixed warnings"

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, scala-collections

I have to use a mutable linked list for a specific use case. However I'd like to avoid **"Reference must be prefixed"** warnings.

Aliasing the import seems to be a solution:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{LinkedList => MutableLinkedList}
```

it works on most cases except in pattern matching an empty LinkedList, this still produces the warning:

```
case MutableLinkedList() => // do Something
```

the only way I can remove this warning seems to be to do a fully qualified case check on an empty list:

```
case scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList() => // do Something
```

Why does the first case not get rid of the warning?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just import `mutable` package:

```
import collection.mutable
```

and use it with any mutable collection:

```
mutable.LinkedList(1, 2, 3)
```

or if you prefer more concise variant:

```
import collection.{mutable => m}
m.LinkedList(1, 2, 3)
```

It will work with pattern matching also.

Comment: explanation https://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2012/05/26/mutableimmutable-collections-prefix-convention-support/

Answer (score 2):

I tried it in the 2.10.2 shell and didn't see any warnings.

One way of "aliasing" the `mutable.LinkedList` extractor is doing:

```
scala> MutableLinkedList(1,2,3,4,5)
res0: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList[Int] = LinkedList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

scala> val LL = MutableLinkedList
LL: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList.type = scala.collection.mutable.LinkedList$@5798795f

scala> res0 match { case LL(1,2, _*) => "yey"; case _ => "bad" }
res3: String = yey
```

See? Now LL points to the `MutableLinkedList` *companion object*

Comment: The warning was coming up in IntelliJ Community Edition, your suggestion works wonderfully. Thanks.